# Automation of inserting images into a Microsoft Word document

Tags: microsoft-word, images, vba, automation

I have a couple of gif in a folder as (1.GIF, 2.GIF etc). How do I **automate** the process of inserting the images into a Microsoft Word document one image per page?

Comment: A macro's one possible solution.

Comment: Would appreciate if some can post the code.

Comment: @Praveen, If you paste the code you have tried so far we can offer some assistance.